# how can i extend the seek bar

Tags: android, seekbar

i am using a seek bar in my application.When i drag the seek bar into the the lay out, it is coming very short. that is i can seek a small area. i checked in the properties, but i cant find out any property to increase the seek area.any body know means please tell me. this is  the screen shot of the application

[image]

Comment: Please post the code of your seek bar, maybe some screen shots also, to help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Err - if you're using the Layout Editor did you try right-clicking the SeekBar and checking the menu point called Layout Width ?

Or simply add it yourself in the .xml file under the SeekBars parameters with:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Unless I am misunderstanding your question greatly this should be quite straight-forward.

Comment: i tried with android:layout_width="fill_parent" then also it remains the same

Comment: Works just fine for me. Tried putting in various dip values (50dip, 100dip etc.) and seeing if that works? Should be no problem.

Comment: ok ..can you see the digital clock, just below the "tesing2". i want to change the digit color into red. how  can i change that

Answer (score 0):

make sure that it is in a large container object.. try:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" >        
    <SeekBar android:max="100" 
             android:progress="0" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:id="@+id/bar">
    </SeekBar>
</TableLayout>
```